# List own deleted questions in profile

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

Even if deleted, sometimes it can be useful to have access to one of *our own* old questions. This is especially true if the question has been automatically deleted by Roomba *without the original poster noticing*.

I know that *if I keep the URL of the question in my bookmarks*, then I (as a < 10k-rep user) can still see it. This would require to maintain a personal list of bookmarks of questions/answers in case they are deleted one day by Roomba.

The problem is that I can't find the question anymore:

- by going in my profile page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/userid/username and see the question list
- by doing this query in the search field `user:me keyword_in_the_question`

**Suggestion: can we still list the deleted questions in the profile page https://stackoverflow.com/users/userid/username  or when doing a query `user:me keyword...`?**

Or at least authorize it for user with <strike>> 10k rep</strike>  > 2k users?

Note: as pointed by @BDL, this could even be useful for > 10k users who might not have access to these questions in their profile too (I cannot check, I'm not a 10k user!).

Comment: If possible, could downvoters explain why it's a bad thing to authorize users to find their questions?

Comment: Its more that this question may face [this has been suggested numerous times already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). TL;DR you can see deleted content in your user profile, but there is a deliberate cut-off age. Still, I kind of like the suggestion of being able to see them all when you do a filtered search.

Comment: @Stijn: I agree that 10k users able to see *all deleted questions* is helpful for moderating reasons. But at least please let any user see *just his own* deleted questions ;)

Comment: I think for lists in the own profile, the same things apply for all users. I don't think >10k users see their deleted questions forever (but I could be wrong). What they can see is the deleted content of everyone **when they have a link to it**

Comment: @Stijn: my bad: my title wasn't very clear. I changed the title to make it clearer :)

Comment: @BDL then it requires that we often maintain a bookmark list of 0 or 1-voted questions in case it might get a downvote and eventually be roomba'd one day

Comment: I didn't mean to say that your request is bad. I just wanted to state that it actually has nothing to do with beeing above or below 10k, so if I'm correct, you might want to edit that part completely out. It just confuses readers. I had to read several times because the first time I thought you want to extend the "see deleted content from everyone" feature to <10k users.

Comment: Oh ok I see @BDL. I didn't know that, because I have never been a > 10k user yet ;)

Comment: @BDL I updated the question, is it more correct now?

Comment: I think so. But in general, it is still a dupe to the meta.SE question linked by Gimby.

Comment: @BDL yeah it comes op on MSO regularly too, but it is usually hidden away in posts about being question/answer banned.

Comment: @Gimby The meta.SE question is highly upvoted, is there a plan for an update about this? Who could accept such a feature request  (probably just one line to change in SE's code : `var show_own_deleted_questions_min_rep = 10000;` to `=200`) and commit, when they are highly accepted by the community? Do you know a SE team user we could ping on this? :)

Comment: @Basj Notice that status-declined tag on it?

Comment: @Gimby Oops, didn't see this. I still can't understand why I couldn't find my own Roomba'd-deleted questions. Imagine you spend time writing a detailed question, 0 vote, few attention, 1 year later someone randomly downvotes, boom Roomba'd, question disappeared! The OP can't find it anymore if he hasn't stored a link somewhere.

Comment: @Basj maybe because of the cut-off time I mentioned? After 60 days, they disappear from the list.

Comment: @Gimby: still, if you write a detailed question, 0 vote, few attention, 1 year later someone randomly downvotes, boom Roomba'd, question disappears without you noticing! Then maybe 80 days after, you think "I knew I already had this question in the past, but why can't I find anymore?". Everything is done quietly (the deletion) and the 60 days don't help.

Comment: You're describing a bit of a niche-case there. Fact of the matter remains that nobody answered or upvoted it in all that time.

Comment: It's not really a niche @Gimby - it's one of the typical situations for questions to be Roomba-deleted : 0 votes or less, more than 1 year, etc.

Comment: I'm disengaging here, this is going nowhere. Meanwhile I found this interesting MSE thread [about roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion), you may want to read it. At this point I really don't know what problems you're seeing, so hopefully threads that are indicators that by golly it is something that is under scrutiny will satisfy you somehow.

Comment: *1 year later someone randomly downvotes,* No, a user came across your question and didn't find it useful. That is not a random down vote, that is a user that understands what to do with their votes. That questions that didn't get any votes get deleted is a good thing. If you want to prevent your questions being roomba-ed, care about them earlier.

Comment: Preventing users from recovering their own posts is very user-hostile design that's disrespect of the time users put it. It's the wrong choice even if it mitigates a little bit of bickering. Forever +1.

Comment: @rene Your comment is missing the point of the comment you're replying to. He's not saying "my post deserved not to be deleted". He's saying "I deserve to know if it's been deleted, so I can keep track of it myself, and the system is designed in a way to **intentionally hide that from me**".

Comment: @JeremyBanks well that is your take on it. I stand by my *take care about them earlier*. I'm very much in favor of removing stuff frictionless if it deemed of not enough value.

Comment: @Basj I've [thrown another bounty on the MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/134300), for what it's worth.

Comment: @rene I definitely do agree with the Roomba design overall. I think we just differ in how we feel about its result in combination with the treatment of deleted posts.

Comment: @JeremyBanks The problem is that I'm not helped at all once I got to my deleted post. What am I supposed to do? Copy and paste it as a new post? Undelete it? I'm an answerer, the question got deleted. You have plenty of opportunity to store the post in your own collection of marbles *before* it got deleted.

Comment: @rene There is a world outside of Stack Overflow. I have re-used Stack Overflow questions to ask internal colleagues for help when they wouldn't post online. Or they could turn it into a blog post. There are many options if we don't erase their effort.

Comment: For the sake of meta posts it's very useful to keep old own deleted questions as a "bad example" or a "unfair DV+delete" example so you can link to them. Unfortunately, even with 70k+, you still can't see them. Which isn't even a storage issue since all posts are kept and visible (<10k) provided you bookmarked them. Good idea.

Comment: @JeremyBanks *world outside of Stack Overflow* ... you tell me now. Okay I give you the blog post option, fair enough.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre With >10k rep you can [search for your own deleted posts by using `deleted:yes` as one of the search options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3Ayes). This allows you to find all of your deleted posts (i.e. not just those posted and deleted in the last 60 days).

Comment: very interesting, good to know. useful to find old shames :)