# Can a moderator help me find two of my deleted answers?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Sometime around end of Dec 2018 I had 2700 answers.

During Jan 2019 suddenly one disappeared. I used `deleted:1` to search for deleted answers and found none in Jan (last were 21 Dec., which I deleted myself)

In beginning of Feb 2019 I added one more, to get back to my 2700.

Just now I noticed one answer disappeared again.

Can someone tell me what's going on, why it was removed, why I can't see which one were removed, and by whom (or what) ?

**Edit**

It's suggested it could have been converted into a comment, and if, how can I possible find it when not knowing which one and when, given I e.g. have +10k of comments?

I am asking this as, now I have no possibilities to act on it being deleted, and I would like that.

Comment: Maybe an answer converted to a comment? Pretty sure some of those do not appear as “deleted answers”; although I do not remember the specific circumstances for it.

Comment: Maybe, though as I can't see which and by whom, I have no possibilities to act on it, and I would like that. Instead of simply do that, notify me and allow for me to either edit the answer, or delete it myself and turn it into a comment.

Comment: Does `deleted:1` include answers to deleted _questions_?

Comment: @Turnip Good question, have no clue, hence am asking what goes on.

Comment: @Turnip Yes it does, I just checked.

Comment: @yivi If it were converted, shouldn't then I find it among my comments?

Comment: I guess it would. But you would need to know where to look for it. You have 
10,273 comments, so unless you know which question your deleted answer was answering it would probably be hard to find wihthout diamond help.

Comment: @yivi Exactly, hence my question here (made en edit to cover that).

Comment: Yeh raises an interesting question. We don't have to tools to see When an answer was deleted. hmm

Comment: @YvetteColomb I will post a question later at `meta.stackexchange.com` (suggested by Rob ♦)

Comment: @YvetteColomb https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324502/an-answer-disappeared-by-the-roomba-process

Comment: It's always the same problem, discussed many times before, but it seems that SO doesn't want to change the policy about this, unfortunately. Proposition: [A user should *always* be able to find its own content, even if deleted silently by Roomba 2 years before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364720/list-own-deleted-questions-in-profile).

Comment: @Basj Thanks for your comment/link. In one way a possible dupe, in another not, as I don't mean it needs to be available forever.

Comment: @LGSon Yes, more or less (my post is maybe more a feature-request). Sadly it's not implemented yet, and original content we created years ago can be silently deleted without us noticing :(

Comment: @Basj Do note, mine is also a `feature-request` though not ask for it to be forever available, just within the rules of the e.g. "deleted recent answers", so one have some chance to act on it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I found your deleted answer in January by checking your reputation history. I'm not sure who has access to see deleted posts there (potentially 10k+ users, or the owner), but here it is:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48485378

That entire question was deleted as part of the automated [Roomba process](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)

For your recently deleted answer... unfortunately, there was no reputation change which makes it somewhat difficult to find. However, we're lucky that the most recent backup for [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) captured all your 2700 answers. This let me grab all the IDs of your undeleted answers as of Sunday, and compare that with your *current* list of answers via the API.

So, without further ado... your recently deleted answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293895) which was deleted by the Community user when the author's account was deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It then means, answers deleted with a _question deletion_ won't show up as "recent deleted answer", unless I deleted it myself? ...and if too old, also not traceable for a moderator...

Comment: @LGSon Apparently not, unfortunately. They are traceable for mods, but since you've got quite a few deleted answers (in the hundreds) - going through every one would take a *long* time

Comment: Does that mean deleted answers is sorted when created, not when deleted? ... If they were sorted when deleted, you would found my 2 more or less at the top.

Comment: @LGSon We can sort by activity date, which does appear to include the date of the answer deletion. However, it doesn't look like it takes question deletion into account when calculating the last activity of the answer

Comment: Ahh...okay, that makes some sense (from a developers perspective :), then a system update would be needed to fix that ;) ... should you or I add that as a `feature-request`, so we can see those answers as well? (might be more effective if done by you :)

Comment: @LGSon This *might* be the post that was deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51574444/563532 - Deleted Sept last year, after you last checked in Feb. Edit: Nevermind, that was self deleted

Comment: @LGSon The poster won't have an affect on effectiveness of the request, but if you do want to post a feature request, it'd be a good fit for https://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd post you found...it isn't it (and you don't need to look more as now we know what goes on).  With that one I deleted my own answer and closed as a dupe, then the question were auto-deleted in Sep.

Comment: @LGSon Figured out a way to get that information for you - thanks to SEDE

Comment: Again, thanks for your time. Does that mean there is a way to find those posts, though not for me? ...and would a `feature-request` for users still be a reasonable question to ask?

Comment: It was possible here only due to the timings - but yes, no moderator tools were needed. In a week, it'd be quite difficult to find the post as SEDE updates every Sunday with the live data. As for the feature request, it *might* be useful, but it's very rare for moderators to need to search by the time of deletion *including* the question's deletion time

Comment: Well, I think, for me as a user, I would wan't to see those deleted answer as well, so will post something.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324502/an-answer-disappeared-by-the-roomba-process

Comment: 10k users and the owners of the question and/or any answers can see the entire post IIRC.

Comment: Is it common for posts to be deleted when a user is deleted? That's not mentioned in the Roomba help page.

Comment: @DavidG yes it is: *If the question is more than 365 days old, and ... has a score of 1 and a deleted owner*

Comment: @CalvT Ah yes, missed that. The confusion being that it was way more than 365 days old. Thanks

Comment: @DavidG although the help page is still incomplete, as another of the conditions is *has no answers* while this one certainly did.

Comment: @CalvT So I was still right that the help page doesn't mention it (technically!)

Comment: @DavidG so I did a bit of digging, and found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) on meta.SE. Point 11 there says *The system will automatically delete any post with a negative score when its owner's account is deleted, unless the post is a question that has at least one positively-scored answer.* The answer in question here had no votes - a score of 0. So the info is there, just not in the right places.

Comment: @CalvT That logic isn't clear to me. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293815/how-to-find-the-libraries-necessary-for-an-example-script/43293895#43293895) had a positive score so fails that test.

Comment: @Zoe Yes but you can't *search* for them even with 10k rep (or any amount of rep), and users can only see recently deleted posts of their own for 30 days. So if OP doesn't bookmark every single answer he writes... he's out of luck without mod help.